# Data analysis - memory bug c++

Tags: c++, variables, memory

I am a data scientist, currently working on some C++ code to extract triplet particles from a rather large text file containing 2D coordinate data of particles in ~10⁵ consecutive frames. I am struggling with a strange memory error that I don't seem to understand.

I have a vector of structs, which can be divided into snippets defined by their frame. For each frame, I build an array with unique ID's for each individual coordinate pair, and if at any point the coordinate pair is repeated, the coordinate pair is given the old coordinate pair. This I then use later to define whether the particle triplet is indeed a trimer.
I loop over all particles and search forward for any corresponding coordinate pair. After I'm done, and no particles were found, I define this triplet to be unique and push the coordinates into a vector that corresponds to particle IDs.

The problem is: after the 18th iteration, at line `trimerIDs[i][0] = particleCounter;` , the variable trimerCands (my big vector array) suddenly becomes unreadable. Can this be that the vector pointer object is being overwritten? I put this vector fully on the heap, but even if I put it on stack, the error persists.

Do any of you have an idea of what I might be overlooking? Please note that I am rather new at C++, coming from other, less close to the metal, languages. While I think I understand how stack/heap allocations work, especially with respect to vectors/vector structs, I might be very wrong!

The error that Eclipse gives me in the variables tab is:

```
Failed to execute MI command:
-data-evaluate-expression trimerCands
Error message from debugger back end:
Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff0000000a
```

The function is as follows.

```
struct trimerCoords{
    float x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3;
    int frame;
    int tLength1, tLength2, tLength3;
};

void removeNonTrimers(std::vector<trimerCoords> trimerCands, int *trCandLUT){

    // trimerCands is a vector containing possible trimers, tLengthx is an attribute of the particle;
    // trCandLUT is a look up table array with indices;

    for (int currentFrame = 1; currentFrame <=framesTBA; currentFrame++){                  // for each individual frame
        int nTrimers = trCandLUT[currentFrame] - trCandLUT[currentFrame-1];                // get the number of trimers for this specific frame
        int trimerIDs[nTrimers][3] = {0};                                                  // preallocate an array for each of the inidivual particle in each triplet;
        int firstTrim = trCandLUT[currentFrame-1];                                         // first index for this particular frame
        int lastTrim = trCandLUT[currentFrame] - 1;                                        // last index for this particular frame

        bool found;
        std::vector<int> traceLengths;
        traceLengths.reserve(nTrimers*3);

        // Block of code to create a unique ID array for this particular frame
        std::vector<Particle> currentFound;
        Particle tempEntry;
        int particleCounter = 0;
        for (int i = firstTrim; i <= lastTrim; i++){                            

            // first triplet particle. In the real code, this is repeated three times, for x2/y2 and x3/y3, corresponding to the 
            tempEntry.x = trimerCands[i].x1;
            tempEntry.y = trimerCands[i].y1;
            found = false;
            for (long unsigned int j = 0; j < currentFound.size(); j++){
                if (fabs(tempEntry.x - currentFound[j].x) + fabs(tempEntry.y - currentFound[j].y) < 0.001){
                    trimerIDs[i][0] = j; found = true; break;
                }
            }
            if (found == false) {
                currentFound.push_back(tempEntry);
                traceLengths.push_back(trimerCands[i].tLength1);
                trimerIDs[i][0] = particleCounter;
                particleCounter++;
            }


        }
        // end block of create unique ID code block

        compareTrips(nTrimers, trimerIDs, traceLengths, trimerfile_out);
    }
}
```

If anything's unclear, let me know!

Comment: A memory debugging tool, such as valgrind in Linux, would likely be very helpful here.

Comment: `int trimerIDs[nTrimers][3] = {0};` looks troubling, as variable length arrays aren't part of the C++ language, and `nTrimers` could also be negative.

Comment: note this code uses Variable Length Arrays, this is not a supported or standard feature and has known major issues resulting in them being banned in many major code bases. I'd highly suggest using `std::vector` instead

Comment: `std::vector<int> traceLengths;` -- You used `std::vector` here, but didn't realize you need to use it here: `int trimerIDs[nTrimers][3] = {0}`.  As noted, this is not valid C++.

Comment: I second Fred Larson's "valgrind" suggestion.  Your error may be the result of an accumulation of Undefined Behaviors.  Running your program in valgrind will identify the _first_ invalid memory access.

Comment: Note passing in `std::vector<trimerCoords> trimerCands` by value may cause a copy. If this is intended behavior that's fine. If it's not and your'e only reading from the vector you can use `std::span` (c++20) or `const std::vector<trimerCoords>& trimerCands` to pass by const reference.

Comment: The truly horrifying thing about programing is the bug is seldom near the crash site. Often the bug mortally wounds the program and staggers on for a while after, finally falling down and dying at an innocent location. The crash site is a vital location to inspect, because it gets the investigation started, but a single function is usually too small a surface area to inspect when you have a complicated program.

Comment: `std::vector<std::array<int, 3>> trimmerIDs(nTrimmers);` -- That replaces the line that was pointed out is not valid C++.

Comment: Thanks for your responses - indeed, the preallocation of a variable length array was the problem. I wasn't even aware this wasn't allowed in standard c++. Something new learned.